# Custom post type single page 404

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, single

I have read a lot similar questions, but none of them saves me.

The site have multi-custom post type registered, others are ok to load a single page, except one,

```
function cabinet_post_type(){
$labels = array(
    'name'                => __('Cabinets'),
    'singular_name'       => __('Cabinet'),
    'menu_name'           => __('Cabinets'),
);

$args = array(
    'description'         => __('Cabinets'),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'genesis-seo', 'genesis-cpt-archives-settings'),
    'show_in_rest'        => true,
    'public'              => true,
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'query_var'           => true,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-editor-ul',
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'can_export'          => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'yarpp_support'       => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'capability_type'     => 'page'
);

register_post_type('cabinet', $args);}
```

I have no cue how that happens, could any big boss figure that out? so many thanks

Comment: Visiti permalinks to flush them.

Comment: As @vancoder said you can flush permalinks - Settings > Permalinks > Save

Answer (score 0):

After a long search! I found a simple answer on a similar case.
just add this line in the custom post type register

```
"taxonomies" => [ "category", "product-category" ],
```

then it will do the magic!